# Vue Access Data from function in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using apex charts (https://apexcharts.com/) to show some data dynamically and some of this data might be currencies, some might be percentages and so on.

I have a component which has the data type in the data function like so:

```
data: function(){
  return{   
    chartOptions: {
      colors: ['#FEB910', '#00ABE7', '#949698'],
       height: 500, 
       dataType: 'percentage' // dynamic - could be currency, percentage etc.... 
       chart:{
         toolbar:{
           show:true
         }
       },
       yaxis: {
        labels: {
          formatter: function (value) {
            console.log(this.dataType) // this is undefined
          }
        },
      },
     }, 
    }
  },
```

Apex charts has a formatting function as you can see, and it works fine but I need a way to check if the dataType variable is percentage or currency so it can format it in a different way. I tried access the 'this' property but it is undefined.

Is there any way I can pass this function the 'this' property? or call it some how?

Comment: Don't use `functions` in the `data` declaration. Use a `computed property` instead.

Comment: You can try using arrow function to use instance of this inside function. formatter: function (value) =>  formatter:(value) =>{ code }

Comment: @Riddhi 's comment works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set the function on mount, which could possibly be substituted for a computed property.

```
this.chartOptions.yaxis.labels.formatter = function(value){
     return value + "$";
}
```

After that is set, the formatter function runs and also has access to the '`this`' property